# jqGrid: format options being ignored

Tags: jqgrid

My format options are being ignored:

```
{name:'effectiveDate', 
        width:'80',  
        align: 'center',
        editable:true, 
        formatter: 'date',
        srcformat:'ISO8601Short',
        newformat: 'Y-m-d', 
        edittype:'date', 
        editrules:{
        required:true
               }
}
```

The backend sends json dates in mm-dd-yyyy format. They are correctly parsed by jqGrid, the values are correct and displayed in the grid with m/d/y format, but I cannot change the formatting, no matter what I input for 'newformat', even if I input garbage it will just ignore it and always display m/d/y. Could it be that I'm missing the Formatter module, or is there another explanation? How can I verify if I have the Formatter module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties `srcformat` and `newformat` are the options of formatter. So you should follow [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#column_specific_options) and rewrite the column definition to

```js
{
    name:'effectiveDate', 
    width: 80,  
    align: 'center',
    editable: true, 
    formatter: 'date',
    formatoptions: {
        srcformat:'ISO8601Short',
        newformat: 'Y-m-d', 
    },
    editrules: {
        required:true
    }
}
```

By the way jqGrid don't know `edittype: 'date'`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#edittype). The format `mm-dd-yyyy` is not ISO8601 date format. Correct ISO8601 format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. I hope the sever use the format in the JSON response.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, sorry I obviously didn't pay enough attention to the documentation. Next, I will look at overriding date formatting globally, by modifying the language file, so that a 'd-MMM-Y' (e.g. 23-Apr-2010) is used. I will post another question if I encounter difficulties.